# Access a Shape object via its ID

Tags: vba, shapes, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint slide with 5 shapes on it. I would like to do different things with theses shapes in a macro. How can I change one of these shapes by using the shape ID? For example, I have two shapes with a name of `"Title 1"` but I want to use the one with an ID of 15.

Here is my code:

```
Sub size_n_spread_v()

    Dim j As Integer
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim SldId As Long
    gap = std_gap

    SldId = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
    Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(SldId)

    Call SortMultArray

    new_dim = (total_dim - gap * (lngRow - 1)) / lngRow

    'This works but is not specific:
    'sld.Shapes.("Title 1").Height = new_dim 

    'This would hopefully be specific but the syntax does not work Please HELP!
    'sld.Shapes.("Title 1").Id(15).Height = new_dim

End Sub
```

Does someone know the right syntax to change the shape via ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way, but you could write a simple helper function that you could then use throughout your project to make things easier on yourself. Something like this would work:

```
Public Function GetShapeById(s As Slide, n As String, id As Long) As Shape

    Dim objShape As Shape
    For Each objShape In s.Shapes
        If StrComp(objShape.Name, n, vbTextCompare) = 0 And objShape.Id = id Then
            Set GetShapeById = objShape
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Then you could use it like so:

```
Sub size_n_spread_v()

    ....

    ' Instead of:
    sld.Shapes.("Title 1").Id(15).Height = new_dim

    ' Use:
    GetShapeById(sld, "Title 1", 15).Height = new_dim

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. But I'd rather have it less complicated and would really like to user it in the way I thought it would work. I still hope that it would be possible. The problem is, as I am not so experienced, that I would have to combine your solution with many array functions that are already in my solution. I'm not sure if I would be able to manage that. 
--> Anyone else with an idea?

Comment: Many thanks. I have solved this by iterating through all shapes and then checking weather shape.id and my stored id are the same.

Comment: Good to hear. That's essentially what I do above as well.

Answer (score 1):

The function mentioned above is the only way to get a shape by Id. You have to search through the Shapes collection as there is no equivalent ShapeIndex as there is for SlideIndex. The other solution to find a specific shape is to uniquely identify shapes by adding your own Tag but this is a more complex solution.